# How to query cassandra from hector for a row when I don't know the row key

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have a schema for storing user details. Now from my java code I want to implement a way for checking if user exists by username and password. Problem is ColumnFamilyQuery requires i supply the row key which I the application doesn't know. How will i accomplish this. I am really new to cassandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What data are you using as the row key?

If your enforcing Username uniqueness in your client code, you can use the Username as the row key itself. That way you can always find a user record by username. Otherwise, you could make a composite key out of the username and some other unique data to avoid collisions.